# Is it possible to set a cell color based on the value of the adjacent cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I am not an active user of excel so I am not very certain if coloring the cell based on another cell's value is possible at all.

Suppose I have these cells:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdbv6.png]

I want the cell with `Good string` to be colored green the same way as `YES` cell is. Same goes to `Bad string` cell.

The final result should look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ4TF.png]

Is it possible to do in MS Excel 2013 and how?

Comment: What do you mean based on the other value? Do you want to determine the color based on the adjacent cell's color? Or the adjacent cell's value?

Comment: two cells, first contains `some string` second contains `YES`/`NO` keyword. I want the first(left) cell to be filled with green if the second(right) is `YES` and red if it is `NO`

Comment: How are the "Yes" and "No" cells being colored now? Are you using conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes, I use conditional formatting rules to color `YES` as green and `NO` as red. But I'd rather have the left-adjacent cells colored if the right cell is `YES`/`NO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible with Excel 2010, which is one of your tags if not directly referenced in your question.

Create a conditional format for one of the cells on the left which references the cell to its immediate right.  You should do this with the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* option of the Rules Manager.

Create a rule for red/green on yes/no as you require.

The creation will automatically place $ symbols in the formula which, of course, restrict the formula to a cell.

Edit the formula in the Rules Manager to remove the $ from the column.

Save the formula

Use *Format Painter* to paste the formula down the whole left hand column.

You will end up with something like the following in the Rules Manager.

There are probably simpler ways to do it but this works for me.

[image]